# Android animation build cube tower on touch event

Tags: java, android, animation, graph

I'm very new to android development.I'v a simple task to do , trying to build cube tower which will growth by one cude each time the user touch the tower base.

please suggest me how to start doing this task OR perhaps share some relevant code (or the exact code :))

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an onClickListener on the view that represents the base of the tower. In the click handler, create the new Cube view programmatically.

If your cubes are in a LinearLayout then (assuming you have a variable called linearLayout that represents the LinearLayout) you can call linearLayout.addView(cubeView, 0). That will add it to the top.